# What do the variables mean in the SVM objective function?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

For a linear SVM, the documentation tells me the formula is:
$$\frac{1}{2}w^Tw + C\sum_{i=1}^l\xi_i.$$

Please explain to me in layman's terms what $w$ and $ξ$ represent.
Is *w* the distance to the hyperplane, the weight of different variables, ... ?

Also, is there a difference with the formula
$$f(x)=w^T x+b$$
or is it just a different notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those two formulae are different things:

- $\frac{1}{2} w^T w + C \sum \xi_i$ is one form of the *objective function*, the function which is minimized over $w$, $b$, and $\xi_i$ (subject to certain constraints, which are where $b$ comes in) to find the best SVM solution.
- Once you've found the model (defined by $w$ and $b$), predictions on new data $x$ are done by finding their distance from the decision hyperplane, $f(x) = w^T x + b$.

$w$ and $b$ define the decision hyperplane, which separates positives from negatives, $\{ x \mid w^T x + b = 0 \}$. So $w$ is perpindicular to that hyperplane. $|w_j|$ is also the weight of the corresponding feature dimension: if $w_j = 0$, that feature is ignored, and if $|w_j|$ is high, that feature is important to the SVM's decision (assuming all the features are scaled similarly).

SVMs are trained by maximizing the *margin*, which is the amount of space between the decision boundary and the nearest example. If your problem isn't linearly separable, though, there is no perfect decision boundary and so there's no "hard-margin" SVM solution. This is why the "soft-margin" SVM was introduced, which allows some points to be on the wrong side of the margin.

$\xi_i$ is the *slack variable* defining how much on the wrong side the $i$th training example is. If $\xi_i = 0$, the point was classified correctly and by enough of a margin; if it's between 0 and 1, the point was classified correctly but by less of a margin than the SVM wanted; if it's more than 1, the point was classified incorrectly. ($\xi_i$ isn't allowed to be negative.) Points with $\xi_i > 0$, as well as those with $\xi_i = 0$ closest to the decision boundary, are known as *support vectors* because they "support" the margin. These are important in a kernel SVM because they're the only ones you need to worry about when predicting on new data.

$C$ is a parameter of the problem that defines how soft the margin should be. As $C \to \infty$, you get a hard SVM; if $C = 0$, the SVM doesn't care about getting the right answer at all and will just choose $w = 0$. In practice, you usually try a few different values of $C$ and see how they perform.

This picture ([source](http://steve-cronin.blogspot.com/2010/09/modern-analytics-look-at-smo.html)) illustrates the different variables, though it's for a kernel SVM; just say $\phi(x) = x$ and it'll be a linear SVM.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This clears up a lot.
Just to see if I understood correctly:
1. The first formula generates the model/hyperplane.  The second formula then decides on which side new data points fall (pos. or neg.) depending on w and b (b being a constant for adjustments).  
2. The weight vector of the feature represents the distance to the seperating hyperplane?

Comment: 1 is correct. 2 not quite: the distance from a point $x$ to the separating hyperplane is $|w^T x - b| = |f(x)|$. Each feature has only a single associated weight $w_j \in \mathbb{R}$, which is something like the importance of that feature but not quite.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Dougal.  So does a single data point in the picture you attached correspond with a row in [this matrix](http://imgur.com/BfnwkZE) or with a singe cell?  I suspect it's a single row (day) having a value `wTx (+b)` with an associated weight for all 35 features X?  (sorry if this is a stupid question)

Comment: I also see you mentioned “points with ξi≠0 are known as support vectors”. Yet, in your picture, I see a data point on the same margin line (+1) as a "Support Vector" and that is ξ=0.  Could you clarify this please?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, support vectors can have $\xi = 0$ if they're right on the margin. In your picture, if you want to classify days based on 35 different features, then each data point would be a 35-dimensional vector corresponding to a row of the matrix, and $w$ would also be 35-dimensional.

Comment: Ah, so a single point corresponds to a row. Thank you very much! As you said, I want to classify days based on the 35 features. Each column represents a person.  Every cell contains a score [-1 to 1] for a person on a certain day.  So cell 11 (day1, X1) would represent the score for person 1 on day 1. Then this matrix would be used for prediction purposes.  The 35 scores (each with their own weight) in row 1 (day 1) would be used to predict a trend (+1 or -1) on day 1, etc. etc.  By the way, isn't `f(x)= wTx +b` just a fancy way of writing `y=ß1x1 + ß2x2 + ... + ß35x35 + b` then?

Comment: @Glenn yes, it's a much shorter way of writing the same thing. :)

Comment: One final thing (promise): Sometimes my C is close to 0. Several (2^-10 to 20^10) were tried on validation data and the model with the best accuracy was executed on the testing data. In your answer you said a C=0 means the SVM doesn't really care about the right answer. Does this mean my features have no real separative (and thus predictive) value? Or is a small C value normal when your weight and feature values are small too. Not too surprising, the auc scores are low too, but I don't know how to find the confidence interval of a random ROC curve/AUC to see whether it's "acceptable".

Comment: $2^{-10}$ is small but not absurd for $C$, and yes, if your feature values are small then $C$ will also be smaller. If your fit isn't good you could try a nonlinear kernel....

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense. I was instructed to use a linear kernel, so I can't use another one. I was told the Confidence Interval of a random ROC curve/AUC score was pretty wide, so maybe the fit is ok after all?  Do you happen to know of a way to determine the CI for this?

Comment: You could try bootstrapping, but this is now to the point where you should ask a new question. :)

Comment: @Dougal "Points with ξi≠0 are known as support vectors because they "support" the margin" This is incorrect.

Comment: @rightskewed I think your proposed edit was also slightly incorrect; the support vectors should be both the points with $\xi_i > 0$ as well as the exactly-on-the-margin points with $\xi_i = 0$. It should be right now; thanks.

Comment: +1. Consider editing the question though: it is strangely formatted and has a completely uninformative title. It's obviously not your fault, but I think things like that can reduce visibility of your answer quite substantially.

Comment: @Dougal I am not sure if that is correct. My reference: Page 11: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf

Comment: @rightskewed Page 11 of that document is talking about hard-margin SVMs, which don't have the $\xi_i$ slack variables. The real distinction for what's a support vector is whether the dual variable $\alpha_i > 0$, but my answer doesn't discuss those. I think $\alpha_i > 0$ iff ($\xi_i > 0$ or $\lvert w^T x + b \rvert = 1$), but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Also clears up a lot of things for me. Thanks!